# In WPF How Do You Capture Part of a Canvas to Save as a BMP or GIF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have an application that generates a replay of Air Traffic and I need to allow the user to capture parts of the canvas so it can be exported as a BMP of GIF.   I did this in VB6, but not sure how to do it in WPF.  I plan on drawing a rectangle around the intended capture area following the mouse till the user triggers the capture.

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [WPF Interactive Image Cropping Control](http://69.10.233.10/KB/WPF/ImageCropper.aspx) mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716626/how-to-make-a-resizeable-rectangle-selection-tool/716664#716664) might be close to what you're after.

You might also check out the [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) class to copy the selected region.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dommer,
I am trying to capture part of a Canvas, and that part most likely will not start with the upper left corner 0,0. I got RenderTargetBitmap to work, but I can not figure out how to set the upper left corner.  

Thanks,

Dave